# WSL2 ubuntu Mongod Keeps changing ports whenever I start a local server up

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I followed this link to setup mongodb on ubuntu wsl, and it kind of worked
https://github.com/michaeltreat/Windows-Subsystem-For-Linux-Setup-Guide/blob/master/readmes/installs/MongoDB.md

However, whenever I use the command `sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`

It will open a Mongod server locally and display this

```
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/home/misterjoe/data/db" } }
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /home/misterjoe/data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
    2020-05-07T14:50:56.880-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=5840M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.360-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588888257:360834][18606:0x7f3480c394c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 6/13440
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.409-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588888257:409482][18606:0x7f3480c394c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 6 through 7
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.441-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588888257:441849][18606:0x7f3480c394c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 7 through 7
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.467-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588888257:467231][18606:0x7f3480c394c0], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.486-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.488-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/home/misterjoe/data/db/diagnostic.data'
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.489-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] listening via socket bound to 127.0.0.1
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.489-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] listening via socket bound to /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
    2020-05-07T14:50:57.489-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Then if I start an application with a mongo database I get this

```
2020-05-07T14:53:19.392-0700 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60332 #1 (1 connection now open)
2020-05-07T14:53:19.395-0700 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:60332 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.5.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.19.84-microsoft-standard" }, platform: "'Node.js v13.10.1, LE (legacy)" }
```

I am trying to keep it on the same port so I can use mongodb compass and have it go to a certain db of my choice. Like RedditClone or todoApp database. However if I type in that IP into it doesn't exist, and the only way I can see anything from this database is by using a .find({}) in javascript. Please help :(

Comment: Those are the client application ports, not mongod ports. Mongod is listening on the default port of 27017 (you can change it with the command line option `-p`) as shown in the line `2020-05-07T14:50:57.489-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017`. If you are trying to connect from a different machine, heed the warnings it is giving you.

Comment: Im connecting with this though "mongodb://localhost:27017/reddit-db" and it doesn't seem to be going to port 27017. Even if I do the --port 27017 on starting Mongo as well it keeps changing the port number for the Mongo application. This time it is 127.0.0.1:60452

Answer (score 0):

What is your actual problem? Everything in your logs shows that you have set up a server and are able to successfully connect to it (from your local machine). It doesn't look like Compass provides a way to set a default database, like the mongo shell command line. If you can browse the available databases or create a new database in Compass, then you have connected to the server.

```
2020-05-07T14:50:57.489-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

This line indicates your started the server and it is listening on localhost:27017

```
2020-05-07T14:53:19.392-0700 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60332 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

This line indicates a new client successfully opened a connection to this server (in your case hosted on port 27017) from port 60332.

If you run the mongo shell, you will see another connection get opened to the server in the logs. Each client (in your case it sounds like Compass) will run on a dynamic port so you can run multiple clients at the same time. You don't connect to the client ports, just the server. The client port is telling the server what port to return results to.

The database specified in the URL is the authentication database, and since you don't have authentication enabled, it is ignored. To quote the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/):

> ```
> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **defaultauthdb**
>
> Optional. The authentication database to use if the connection string includes username:password@ authentication credentials but the authSource option is unspecified.
>
> If both authSource and defaultauthdb are unspecified, the client will attempt to authenticate the specified user to the admin database.

Comment: It says permission denied when I try to connect to this with MongoDB compass not showing me the database that was created